# how to make pop up window and parent window both active

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open a pop up window and submit data through it. But as soon as I click outside of this small window, this popup gets closed. I want that both the windows should be active.
Please help

Comment: Are you using bootstrap modal popup window ?

Comment: Please, explain a little bit more what you want to do, and what you have tried, and which library you are using.

Comment: I have a noting editor and I want to write on it by seeing all the submitted notings in a small window. But as soon as I bring cursor on this editor, the opened small window gets closed. I have tried several plugins, but none re working in IE 11.

Comment: Please post some code so we have any chance to be able to help